# Simple if/else statements error

Tags: c, if-statement

So I have this program which converts F to C and vice versa,and I want to modify it so that it doesn't accept temperatures below absolute zero as a valid input. For some reason I'm getting an errors at this line:

```
else if (Celsius < -273.15)
   {
   printf("ERROR! The temperature is below absolute zero.");
   }
```

This is my entire code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float c2f(float);
float f2c(float);

float Fahrenheit,Celsius;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

/** 
 * Check for the expected number of arguments (3)
 * (0) program name
 * (1) flag
 * (2) temperature
 */
if (argc!=3)
{
    printf("Incorrect number of arguments\n");
    exit(0);
}

if (!strcmp(argv[1], "toF"))
{
   // convert the string into a floating number
   char *check;
   float Celsius = strtod(argv[2], &check);

   else if (Celsius < -273.15)
   {
   printf("ERROR! The temperature is below absolute zero.");
   }

// process from celsius to fahrenheit
   Fahrenheit = c2f(Celsius);
   printf("%5.2f°C = %5.2f°F\n",Celsius, Fahrenheit);
}   
else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "toC"))
{
   // convert the string into a floating number
   char *check;
   float Fahrenheit = strtod(argv[2], &check);

   // process from fahrenheit to celsius
   Celsius = f2c(Fahrenheit);
   printf("%5.2f°F = %5.2f°C\n", Fahrenheit, Celsius);
}

else 
{

else
   printf("Invalid flag\n");
} // main


float c2f(float c)
{
  return 32 + (c * (180.0 / 100.0)); 
} 

float f2c(float f)
{
  return (100.0 / 180.0) * (f - 32);
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting because of that line:

part4.c: In function ‘main’:

part4.c:31: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘else’

part4.c:29: warning: unused variable ‘Celsius’

part4.c: At top level:

part4.c:40: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘else’

part4.c:51: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘else’

make: *** [part4] Error 1

**Any thoughts on this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This part is the problem:

```
else if (Celsius < -273.15)
{
   printf("ERROR! The temperature is below absolute zero.");
}
```

Change it to:

```
if (Celsius < -273.15)
{
    printf("ERROR! The temperature is below absolute zero.");
}
```

Also this:

```
else 
{

//else  --> remove this
   printf("Invalid flag\n");
}-->  Add a brace
} // main
```

*Syntactically* corrected code - http://ideone.com/Ej9iJ8